# Cmd/Ctrl+F in iTunes Workflow

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, itunes

Okay, so I'm using iTunes on Snow leopard and I'd like to search for a track, I hit `CMD+F` to get to the the search field (there was hack which I don't remember about to be able to do this), I type the name and get the result. Now, for the life of me, I can't select or switch focus to get to the search results with the keyboard. What gives? Annoying Apple! x-(

Comment: this question is kinda hard to answer without this "hack"

Comment: The "official" shortcut to access the search field in ALT+CMD+F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so i found the hack you were talking about (i think) which was:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Target Search Field" "@F
```

Anyways after I pressed cmd+F to take me to the search field, I found the easiest way to get back to the list pane was to press Tab once, and then press down on the keypad.

Comment: Tab and down key does the trick! I never pressed both in succession. Rather, I wanted the list to take focus when I pressed Tab but since it is a hack, you get the idea. Thanks a lot for your suggestion! :)